# Notnull and empty string in My SQL

Tags: mysql-workbench, string, notnull

Hy I have problem. I wanna to create table with some atributes, and some of them shoud be specified as NOT NULL.. And here comes the problem. When I insert some data into table, and when I insert '' (empty single string) it input data into table, but I dont want this... How to restrict inserting data from inputing single string or inputing nothing..

here are my table

CREATE TABLE tbl_Film
(

ID INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,

Naziv VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

Zanr VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

Opis VARCHAR(150)  NULL,

Kolicina INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL

);

INSERT INTO tbl_Film VALUES (1,'','Animirani','Mala ribica',2)

This input blank data into Naziv, and I don't want that.. I need to restrict that..

http://prntscr.com/21gfgd

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is possible in SQL, but why dont you exchange the '' in your application into the String NULL?

Comment: can you tel me how to do that, because I'm beginner :(. btw I'm using My SQL Workbench

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, `NULL` is not the same as `''` (with the exception of MS SQL via OleDB AFAIR, in which `''` should be stored as `NULL`).

> NULL values represent missing unknown data.
>
> See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp

In regular SQL, you should use a CHECK constraint, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Film (
ID INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
Naziv VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Zanr VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Opis VARCHAR(150) NULL,
Kolicina INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
CHECK (Naziv <> '')
);
```

Sadly, this CHECK constraint is NOT implemented by MySQL:

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines. 
>   See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html

So the only solution I see, at DB level, is to write a [P/SQL trigger](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9668)...